# How to get "Non-Amazon" sales channel order through "Amazon MWS Order API"

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I'm using amazon MWS api to get the complete amazon order list. It's pretty good to have such api which returns Fulfilled by Amazon (AFN) and Fulfilled by the seller (MFN) orders.

I can see all Sales Channels (Amazon, Non-Amazon) orders once i logged in to amazon seller central. But problem is, this api does not return "Non-Amazon" Sales Channel orders.

Note : i'm sending only CreatedAfter parameter with other required parameters.

Is there a any way to get "Non-Amazon" Channel orders through MWS Order API?

Or

Amazon does not provide Non-Amazon sales channel order information through api and if it's true, then it means i have to logged in to seller central and manually note down "Non-Amazon" Channel orders details.

I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non-Amazon sales channel order is either created through merchant or using Fulfillment Outbound Shipment API Action "CreateFulfillmentOrder". To get those orders information back we need to use Fulfillment Outbound Shipment API Action "GetFulfillmentOrder".

These api definitely gonna save lot of time :)

Comment: Do you know how to get by MWS GetOrderList orders with other `Sales Channel`? For example, I have credentials for `AmazonDE` but I see orders inside web interface of Amazon.de, that many orders have `Sales Channel: Amazon.it`. How to get these `amazon.it` orders by API? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To get **Non-Amazon Orders list**, you have to consume "FulfillmentOutbound" Api. Let me note down how you will use this.

For US Marketplace , https://mws.amazonservices.com/scratchpad/index.html
open this link and in API Section select "Fulfillment" option then under Operation you have to select **FulfillmentOutbound -> ListAllFulfillmentOrders**
now you have to fill the seller information and enter the date from which you want to receive orders .